# Static generic field in Java

Tags: java, android, generics, static

I going to implement initialization of fragment with passing my generic field (presenter) and then connect this presenter to created View.

```
public class BaseViewFragment <P extends BasePresenter> extends Fragment implements BaseView {

static private P presenter; //the problme is here, I do not allowed this
static private BaseViewFragment baseViewFragment;
.
.
.

public static <P extends BasePresenter> BaseViewFragment initialize(P presenter) {

    if (baseViewFragment != null) {
        presenter.setView(baseViewFragment);
    } else {

        baseViewFragment = new BaseViewFragment();
        presenter.setView(baseViewFragment);
    }

    BaseViewFragment.presenter= presenter;
    return baseViewFragment;
}
```

But it seems that generic static field is not allowed. How I can handle this?

Comment: @lvl4fi4 Java doesn't care which is used. private static or static private.

Comment: Can you use object and cast it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createStatic):

> Cannot Declare Static Fields Whose Types are Type Parameters
>
> A class's static field is a class-level variable shared by all
>   non-static objects of the class. Hence, static fields of type
>   parameters are not allowed.

It is not possible because a static field is shared by all the instances of the class `BaseViewFragment`, and if allowed, for every new `BaseViewFragment` instance you can specify a new `Generic Type parameter`. So it is not allowed.

What you can do is: pass the Presenter instance to the Fragment using a `setPresenter` method and initialize.

For example,

```
    P presenter; // no need for static

    public BaseViewFragment() {

    }

    public void setPresenter(P presenter) {
       this.presenter = presenter;
    }
```

Set the Presenter:

```
baseViewFragment  = new BaseViewFragment(); 
baseViewFragment.setPresenter(presenter);
```

By the way, having a `Fragment` in a static variable might lead to memory (`Activity`) leaks. Are you clearing that field when the `Fragment` destroys? If not you are leaking your `Fragment` and the bound `Activity` and all the `Views` in it.

Comment: All of my problem starting from here, at first I used constructor for fragment and pass it's presenter but I lead to some fragment crash. It is not good to using fragment constructor. then I came for static method and this happened.

Comment: Yes. I have missed the fact that it's a Fragment. Fragment should have a public empty constructor. That gets called by the system during fragment recreation. I have updated the answer.